# How do I get my game to end when any of the kings (card 13) is picked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I now have a random order of cards however the game will only end when I pick the c13.gif card. I have tried using else if to combat the issue but unfortunatly this does not work. I would you to end the game if any of the number 13 (king) cards have been picked. The game is a similar concept to minesweeper.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Don't Pick the King!</title>

    <table style="width:50%">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_0" onClick="flipCard(0);"></td>
        <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_1" onClick="flipCard(1);"></td>
        <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_2" onClick="flipCard(2);"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_3" onClick="flipCard(3);"></td>
       <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_4" onClick="flipCard(4);"></td>
       <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_5" onClick="flipCard(5);"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_6" onClick="flipCard(6);"></td>
      <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_7" onClick="flipCard(7);"></td>
      <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_8" onClick="flipCard(8);"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_9" onClick="flipCard(9);"></td>
      <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_10" onClick="flipCard(10);"></td>
      <td><img src="cards/b.gif" Class="back" id="card_11" onClick="flipCard(11);"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="score" style="float:center">If you pick a king you lose.</p>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="hard-copy.html">Restart</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <style>
    * {
        background-color: lightblue;
        border-color: hsla(173,100%,50%,1.00);
        font-weight: bold;  
    }
    ul { 
        list-style-type: none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0; <!--- Getting rid of the bullets within the list --> 
    }

    .back
    {width:100px;
    height:100px;
    }

    </style>

    <script language="JavaScript">


    /*ID of each card 0,1,2
                      3,4,5,
                      6,7,8,
                      9,10,11 ---12 cards 0 being the 1st and 11 being 12th card */


    var deck = ["cards/c11.gif","cards/c12.gif","cards/d11.gif","cards/d12.gif","cards/h11.gif",
            "cards/h12.gif","cards/s11.gif","cards/s12.gif","cards/c13.gif", "cards/d13.gif", "cards/h13.gif", "cards/s13.gif"];
    //deck of cards
    function shuffle(deck){ 

        for(swaps=0; swaps<11; swaps++){
            var shuffle1=Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
            var shuffle2=Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
            var temp=deck[shuffle1];
            deck[shuffle1]=deck[shuffle2];
            deck[shuffle2]=temp;
        }
    }
    //for loop there to shuffle from deck the 12 cards
    //var shuffles randomises deck every time game is played
    var disabledCards = [];
    var gameOver = false;

    function flipCard(card) {
      if(!gameOver) //if game not over 
      {
          if(disabledCards[card] !== false) //not equal value or not equal type
          {
              if(deck[card] != "cards/c13.gif")  
              {
                  disabledCards[card] = false; 
                  selection = card;
                  document.images[card].src = deck[card];
              }

              else {
                  gameOver = true;
                  alert("You chose a King!  ¯|_(ツ)_|¯" );
              }
          } else {
              alert("Card has already been clicked! ¯|_(ツ)_|¯" );
          }
      } else {
          alert("Game has already ended!  ¯|_(ツ)_|¯");
      }
    }

    //when user clicks on a card the card will flip over and choose random image from deck
    function onLoad(){
        shuffle(deck);
        }
    //when program first loads up place the cards in a random order
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
    //event listener waits for DOM to finish loading then executes onLoad function
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the flipCard function as shown here to make the game work:

```js
var disabledCards = []; // will hold all of the previously clicked images
var gameOver = false; // when set to true, the game is over and disables the game

function flipCard(card) {
  if(!gameOver) // if gameOver is false
  {
   if(disabledCards[card] !== false) // if this card has not been clicked before
   {
    if(deck[card] != "cards/c11.gif") // if the card is not the king
    {
     disabledCards[card] = false;// add this card to disabled cards list
     document.images[card].src = deck[card]; // flip the card over

    } else { // the card clicked was a king

     gameOver = true; // set gameOver to true
     alert("Whoopsidaisies, you chose a King!");
    }

   } else { // this card has already been clicked

    alert("Card has already been clicked!");
   }

  } else { // gameOver is true
   alert("Game has already ended!");
  }
}
document.onload = onLoad();
```

Using the if statement, we can check to see if either the game has ended, a card was selected again, or if the wrong card was chosen (in this case I made it "cards/c11.gif").  The document.onload allows the cards to shuffle one time after the page loads.

Also make sure you delete the line "deck(1, 0);" because that throws an error.

Comment: would I need to therefore add multiple if else to choose from multiple cards or  somehow use my array before to call each individual king?

Comment: If you use your original code and replace your flipCard function with all of the code I provided, it will work.  I added comments to my code to explain what the code is doing.  I wasn't sure which image your king was so I used "cards/c11.gif", so just change that card to the url of the king image.  And remember to choose an answer when your question has been answered.

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer when your problem has been solved!  If it hasn't been solved, please update your question!

Comment: My bad! Getting used to this forum! Done and dusted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call shuffle every time you pick a card,you could make it execute only once, when the DOM has finished loading. And add the var keyword to the variables. Try this :

```
var deck = ["cards/c11.gif", "cards/c12.gif", "cards/d11.gif", "cards/d12.gif", "cards/h11.gif",
  "cards/h12.gif", "cards/s11.gif", "cards/s12.gif", "cards/c13.gif", "cards/d13.gif", "cards/h13.gif", "cards/s13.gif"
];
deck(1, 0);

function shuffle(deck) {
  for (var swaps = 0; swaps < 12; swaps++) {
    var shuffle1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var shuffle2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var temp = deck[shuffle1];
    deck[shuffle1] = deck[shuffle2];
    deck[shuffle2] = temp;
  }
}

function flipCard(card) {
  selection = card;
  document.images[card].src = deck[card];
}

function onLoad() {
  shuffle(deck)
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
```

Comment: now i just need need to figure out how to end the game on clicking a king. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you shuffling the cards everytime you flip one? I think that is why you are getting duplicates. Try removing `onload();` from the `flipCard` function.

Comment: That gets rid of the duplicates, thanks. However the cards are now in the same place in the grid everytime the game is played.

Comment: You probably want to shuffle only once, when the page finishes loading. Here is more info on how to add a page load callback - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load